# Воспроизведение плейлиста с заданного элемента в Windows Media Player

Tags: c#, аудио, media

Пишу MP3 плеер. В программе предусмотрены плейлисты. То есть, когда пользователь открывает музыку из определённой папки, создаётся плейлист, и вся музыка, что есть в этой папке добавляется в этот плейлист:

```
private void Launch(string audio)
    {
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(audio));

        WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist playlist = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("myplaylist");
        WMPLib.IWMPMedia media;

        foreach (var music in info.GetFiles())
        {
            media = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(music.FullName);
            playlist.appendItem(media); 
        }

        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = playlist;
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();

        save.audio = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.sourceURL;

        this.Text = "MP3";
        this.Text += "  " + Path.GetFileName(audio);

        save.New();
    }
```

Но столкнулся с проблемой, если, например, я выбрал допустим третий трек то воспроизведение плейлиста начнётся не с третьего трека, а с первого. В этом и вся проблема. Я, конечно, могу добавить выбранный трек в самое начало, но тогда музыка будет выводиться не по списку, ибо первым треком будет третий, а вторым первый и тд. Можно ли как-то начать воспроизведение плейлиста с выбранного мною трека?

Answer (score 0):

Свойство [AxWindowsMediaPlayer.currentMedia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/axwmplib-axwindowsmediaplayer-currentmedia--vb-and-c) задает текущий воспроизводимый элемент:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia = playlist.Item[3];
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
```